# Is the New Hampshire version of a criminal threatening law defective?

Tags: criminal-law

In New Hampshire law, RSA 631:4 makes "Criminal Threatening" a crime. The law begins:

> A person is guilty of criminal threatening when: (a) By physical
> conduct, the person purposely places or attempts to place another in
> fear of imminent bodily injury or physical contact; or ... (etc)

This seems like kind of sweeping statement. By comparison the Massachusetts statute (275 Section 2) specifically says that for an act to be criminal threatening, the action threatened *must be a crime*. The New Hampshire does not say this at all. In fact, simply threatening to "place another in fear of imminent...physical contact" is a crime. So, by that standard every high school linebacker would be a criminal because they put the fear of "imminent physical contact" into their opponents.

Also, we can think of many other situations where people are put into "fear of bodily injury" or "contact". Without the constraint that the contact would be unlawful, the law seems to be absurdly open ended.

So, assuming that the law is defective, is there any remedy for this in court? Can a defendant argue that a law is invalid because it is defective?

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overbreadth_doctrine

Comment: Defective in what way? I don't know of any reason a legislature would be barred from enacting absurdly broad laws or outlawing football specifically.

Answer (score -1):

### Why is “in fear of imminent physical contact” over broad?

The person facing the linebacker might be anxious, trepidatious, and excited about the imminent physical contact but, by virtue of it being a normal, everyday and socially accepted form of contact that they consented to, they cannot be “in fear” of it.

Remember that the standard of “fear” is objective - would a reasonable person in the victim’s position be in fear? Not, was the victim in fear? This appears to be nothing more than a codification of common-law assault.

Comment: Do you have any authority for any of this? Every sentence seems to be incorrect.